# STM32F407 UART gives garbage on terminal

Tags: arm, stm32, stm32f4discovery, baud-rate, usart

I have just started my adventures with STM32f407 Discovery board. I'm using latest stable release of CoIDE and using up to date toolchain/libraries.

I managed to write the following code in order to use USART1 from the board

```
int main(void){

GPIO_InitTypeDef  GPIO_InitStructure;   // Definicja struktury do inicjalizacji PINOW
USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

// Initialize pins as alternating function
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_Pin_9 | GPIO_Pin_10;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode    = GPIO_Mode_AF;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType   = GPIO_OType_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd    = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed   = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource9, GPIO_AF_USART1);
GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOA, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART1);

// Modify USART_InitStructure for non -default values , e.g.
// USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 38400;
USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate              = 9600;
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength            = USART_WordLength_8b;
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits              = USART_StopBits_1;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity                = USART_Parity_No;
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl   = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode                  = USART_Mode_Tx|USART_Mode_Rx;
USART_Init(USART1 ,&USART_InitStructure);
USART_Cmd(USART1 , ENABLE);


while(1)
{
    while (USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1 , USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);
    USART1 ->DR = (uint16_t)(45 & 0x01FF);

    Delay(0x3FFFFF);
}
```

}

Also I have made sure clock is configured correctly by setting HSE and other clock details

```
    #if !defined  (HSE_VALUE)
  #define HSE_VALUE    ((uint32_t)8000000) /*!< Value of the External oscillator in Hz */
#endif /* HSE_VALUE */
```

And also

```
    /************************* PLL Parameters *************************************/
/* PLL_VCO = (HSE_VALUE or HSI_VALUE / PLL_M) * PLL_N */
#define PLL_M      8
#define PLL_N      336

/* SYSCLK = PLL_VCO / PLL_P */
#define PLL_P      2

/* USB OTG FS, SDIO and RNG Clock =  PLL_VCO / PLLQ */
#define PLL_Q      7

/******************************************************************************/
```

In console I just receive garbage and I have made the following to make sure the setup is correct : 
- Checked USB-RS232 converter 
- Switched between converter and STM32 board 
- Switched converter 
- Generated code using STM32CubeMX to compare it and it seems consistent (logic wise of course :) )

From my beginner perspective it is kinda "showstopper" :( I cannnot seem to find a root cause of this

Any help would be appreciated

---

UPDATE 1 : In order to find root cause I have decided to try one of the other USART modules. Below is my code for USART3 and this one **WORKS OUT OF THE BOX** which would lead me to incorrect init of USART1 in the initial question ?

```
int main(void)
```

{

```
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
  USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;

  /* Enable GPIO clock */
  RCC_AHB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_AHB1Periph_GPIOC, ENABLE);

  /* Enable UART clock */
  RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_USART3, ENABLE);

  /* Connect PXx to USARTx_Tx*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource10, GPIO_AF_USART3);

  /* Connect PXx to USARTx_Rx*/
  GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIOC, GPIO_PinSource11, GPIO_AF_USART3);

  /* Configure USART Tx as alternate function  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_UP;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  /* Configure USART Rx as alternate function  */
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_11;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 9600;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
  USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Rx | USART_Mode_Tx;

  /* USART configuration */
  USART_Init(USART3, &USART_InitStructure);

  /* Enable USART */
  USART_Cmd(USART3, ENABLE);

  SysTick_Config(SystemCoreClock / 1000);

  while(1)
  {


    for (int var = 45; var < 128; var++)
    {
        USART_SendData(USART3, var);

        Delay_SysTick(500); // 1 sek
    }



  }
```

}

---

Resolution: After a lot of digging and trying multiple things it appears that USART1 would collide with USB components and there is capacitor which collides with the transmission [link to answer on ST forums](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Discovery/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Discovery/Help%20with%20GPIO%20on%20STM32F4%20discovery&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D75800084C20D8867EAD444A5987D47BE638E0F&currentviews=956)

I wish I would have found this somewhere in documentation before.

Hope this helps someone and thanks everyone for your assistance

Comment: Have you tried all possible speeds on the PC end to see if you can find whatever rate it _is_ running at? Getting garbage rather than nothing at least suggests it's _mostly_ working.

Comment: @Notlikethat : I have not been trying alternate speeds. As I have set all of that to run on 9600 and therefore would like to understand root cause of this not working

Comment: @artlessnoise : I have level logic analyzer however the data I receive makes no sense. When for example I want to send decimal 45 which is ASCII "0" ?! I receive 254 on Logic  Analyzer (set to baud rrate 9600)
Also I have used multiple and reliable RS232 converters so this is definitely not an issue there

Comment: My point is, knowing what _is_ happening often helps pin down what _isn't_ happening - e.g. the difference between still running at whatever rate the bootloader configured because something wasn't set, or running at some utterly nonsense rate because the wrong value went into the wrong register. Also, note that decimal 45 is ASCII "-", "0" is 48 (0x30).

Comment: @Notlikethat: Good point. Please do not take my comment as offensive in anyway. It might be just my command of English :) Now in order to try different baud rates ... Should I try a list of default ones ? Cannot grasp idea where to start with this.

Comment: @artlessnoise: It is TTL logic level analyzer.

Comment: I'd try all the standard ones from 9600 up to 115200 first. If I had a scope or logic analyser I'd probably just send an alternating bit pattern like 0xAA and look at the time between edges. Another thing to watch out for with TTL-to-RS232/USB conversion, as well as low-voltage tolerance on <5V systems, is whether the TTL signals are inverted or not.

Comment: I have checked multiple baud rates. While sending single character of value decimal  USART1 ->DR = (48 & 0xFF); For BR 2400 it showed value of 254/ BR 4800 value of 250/ for BR 9600 value of 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USART1 on this board (TX pin) has capacitor which collides with traffic. It is mentioned on [ST forums.](https://my.st.com/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Discovery/Flat.aspx?RootFolder=/public/STe2ecommunities/mcu/Lists/STM32Discovery/Help%20with%20GPIO%20on%20STM32F4%20discovery&FolderCTID=0x01200200770978C69A1141439FE559EB459D75800084C20D8867EAD444A5987D47BE638E0F&currentviews=956)

Answer (score 0):

Garbage on terminal often is caused when the sender has a different baudrate than the receiver.

Comment: I have made sure that my terminal on PC is running in the exactly same settings as UART on discovery (8 bits data / 1 bit stop / no parity / no flow control )